# How to print the current time in the format Day, Date Month Year HH:MM:SS?

Tags: python-2.7, datetime, epoch

How to print the current time in the format `Day, Date Month Year HH:MM:SS`

```
Mon, 28 Aug 2017 15:37:01 .
```

And then, convert this timestamp to epoch seconds & vice-versa.

Comment: Have you explored the `datetime` module?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html. Please walk through this and help yourself

Answer (score 8):

[datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module does all the job

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%a, %d %B %Y %H:%M:%S")
'Tue, 29 August 2017 03:04:21'
```

Comment: `%I` is time in 12hour AM/PM format. To get hours in 24h format, use `%H`.

Comment: how do you get the same but in UTC, this one is printing local time

Comment: @VijayKumar `datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%a, %d %B %Y %H:%M:%S")` for UTC